# infinite intersection of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying  to proof this identity: $ [a,b]\equiv \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty [a,b+\frac{1}{n}) \equiv \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (a-\frac{1}{n} , b]  $

I already try to use De-Morgan's lows but with no success .

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You only need to expand the relevant definitions and use some observations about the real numbers. I leave it to you to combine everything because this is a homework exercise.

*Definitions:*

- $A = B$ iff $x \in A \iff x \in B$; equivalently, $A = B$ iff $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$.
- $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ iff $x\in A_n$ for all $n$.
- $[a,b] = \{x \in \Bbb R: a \le x \le b\}$; $[a,b) = \{x \in \Bbb R: a \le x < b\}$; $(a,b] = \{x \in \Bbb R: a < x \le b\}$.

*Observation:*

What can we conclude if $x < b + \frac1n$ for all $n$? (Hint: suppose $x > b$.) Similarly for $x > a - \frac1n$.